# Nginx in docker container as a reverse proxy to local Apache WordPress webs placed in subfolders

Tags: wordpress, docker, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

Well, for historical reasons, I have a set of let's say 20 WordPress websites placed in /var/www/html/wordpress[1-20] that serves local Apache (port 88) based on their folder structure:

- http://192.168.100.204:88/wordpress1
- http://192.168.100.204:88/wordpress2
- ...

This fully works OK. 192.168.100.204 is IP address of the localhost. I cannot use "localhost" because of the Nginx container. Explained below.

Then, I have **Nginx in** Docker **container** (port 80) that works as a reverse proxy to new projects that are developed in separated containers. That also works fine and it's not the case now.

What I want is to use the Nginx as a reverse proxy also to the old WordPress sites servered by the local Apache.

So, the goal is:

- wordpress1.mydev.tld <- reverse proxy -> http://192.168.100.204:88/wordpress1
- wordpress2.mydev.tld <- reverse proxy -> http://192.168.100.204:88/wordpress2
- ...

Note: *.mydev.tld is a wildcard to 127.0.0.1

I know I need to add following to all the WordPress configs:

```
define('WP_HOME', 'http://wordpress1.mydev.tld/');
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://wordpress1.mydev.tld/');
```

Nginx config of 1 site:

```
location / {
    set              $targetUri http://192.168.100.204:88/wordpress1/;

    if ($request_uri != /){
      set            $targetUri $targetUri$request_uri;
        }
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Scheme $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For    $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
        proxy_pass       $targetUri;
    
        proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";
        sub_filter_types text/html;
        sub_filter '192.168.100.204:88/wordpress1/' 'wordpress1.mydev.tld/';
        sub_filter_once off;
    
      }
    
      location /wordpress1/ {
    
        set              $targetUri http://192.168.100.204:88/wordpress1/;
    
        if ($request_uri != /){
        set            $targetUri $targetUri$request_uri;
        }
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Scheme $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For    $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
        proxy_pass       $targetUri;
    
        proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";
        sub_filter_types text/html;
        sub_filter '192.168.100.204:88/wordpress1/' 'wordpress1.mydev.tld/';
        sub_filter_once off;
    
    }
```

I don't want to write all my not working configs of the Nginx here to not complicate the question. The issue is that the Apache always responds with /wordpress[1-20] subfolder in URI and this prevents proper working. I've tried to handle it by find-and-replacing (sub_filter) or rewriting it (rewrite) but it always ends up with a loop of redirects.

Any help is welcome.